# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'friends'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I was building a Feature BUT i am stuck on a Error.

when i open Detail page then i keep getting :-

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'friends'

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile",blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'

CHOICES = (
    ('everyone','Every One'),
    ('friend','friend only'),
    ('none','Nobody'),
)
```

urls.py

```
path('<id>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

**Explanation of views.py**

My code is supposed to , When i click on `friends only` then it should check `request.user` friends list AND if `request.user` is exist then comment form will show. BUT this is keep showing me `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'friends'` Error.

**The Problem**

When i put `'allow_comments == friend' in views` and select `friend only in Browser` then i got this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Try allow_comment == "friend" not only friend. If not show you trace back error, and code of place where error supposed to be.

Comment: Alway do  self while referencing the same model. If you change the class name later, it will be not good to modify all fields.   friends = models.ManyToManyField("Self",blank=True)

Comment: @Mbambadev, It didn't work.

Comment: Please past your queryset

Comment: Which queryset ?

Answer (score 1):

You save a whole QuerySet in the variable user.
A QuerySet is always an instance of QuerySet.
This is why the object saved under the name user does not have the attributes that an instance of Profile would have.

You should for clarity save the user-object in the variable user and rename that ForeignKey in Post to author.
To get the corresponding instance of Profile you can use the reverse of the OneToOneField you defined:

models.py:

```
...
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
def detail_view(request,id):
    ...
    user = request.user
    ...
    elif (
        post.allow_comments == 'friend'
        and user.is_authenticated
        and user.profile is not None
        and user.profile in post.author.profile.friends.all() 
    ):
        ...
```

Comment: Now I cannot change the whole code. Please suggest me another method

Comment: You don't need to change the whole code. Only the few lines I changed. I just spread out the condition of the if-statement across multiple lines so it is easier to read.

Comment: The ... are just there to indicate the places where the unchanged code would stay.